# What is the ! sign next to my file name in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got this *! sign* next to my file name right after I resolved a merge conflict after running `git stash pop`. Does anyone know what it means and how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there's an unresolved merge conflict and you need to commit any resolution

Comment: oh thanks! it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

It may mean that *you renamed the file* and does not exist in the editor anymore.

Or, the code has errors.

Comment: when there are errors you see a number in the theme error color

Comment: that seems to not be the case. The things I only did is run `git stash pop` and resolved some merge issues. No errors because it works completely fine, and I do not recall renaming the file ever